# How do i import datasets in Python?

Tags: python, import, neural-network, dataset, spyder

I try to import some datasets in my code. I need help, because I tried a lot of tutorials and web pages and I am still gettting errors. I use `Spyder IDE` and `python 3.7`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import os
dts1=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Cucu\Desktop\sample_submission.csv")
dts1
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: for dts1=pd.read_csv('sample_submission.csv') i get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample_submission.csv'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. If you are still experiencing errors, please post them.

```
import pandas as pd 
# Read data from file 'sample_submission.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Cucu\Desktop\sample_submission.csv") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
print(data.head())
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping. it seems working properly but i don't understand why. i wrote before copying your code exactly the same pd.read_csv function as you wrote and still got error. only the variable was different. it was dts1,not data

Comment: dts1=pd.read_csv('name_of_dataset')
dts1=pd.read_csv("name_of_dataset")
dts3=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Cucu\Desktop\sample_submission.csv")
dts4=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Cucu\Desktop\sample_submission.csv") POSTED ON GITHUB

Answer (score 0):

Try using other approaches :

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Cucu\\Desktop\\sample_submission.csv")

pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Cucu/Desktop/sample_submission.csv")
```